# how to set position of CupertinoDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how to set position of CupertinoDatePicker ?

where i can set position of CupertinoDatePicker? Because i get many space in left and right side

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        border: Border.fromBorderSide(
            BorderSide(width: 0.75, color: Color(0xFFEAEAEA)))),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        CupertinoTheme(
          data: CupertinoThemeData(
              textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                  dateTimePickerTextStyle:
                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF313131), fontSize: 16))),
          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            initialDateTime: DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 3)),
            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
              print(newdate);
            },
            use24hFormat: true,
            minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
            minuteInterval: 1,
            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            height: 48,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                    BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.orange)),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

actual :

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

expect :

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

could you help me to fix this?

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: sorry, i've add my code

Comment: any update? i want to custom margin like this too.